# pyinstaller setup failed with "setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation."

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I was trying to "pip install pyinstaller" on my Mountain Lion. It failed with

```
setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation.
```

There is a ticket for this (http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/629) but not helpful.

I was using pythonepd 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says "it is **not** *yet* supposed to work" - if you read the documents you will find that you just unzip/unpack it into a local directory and run it from there.

You are not supposed to run `setup.py` in `pyinstaller` at all - see [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/doc/Manual.html#installing-pyinstaller) for how to set up pyinstaller.
Once installed *and on your path* you run by typing `pyinstaller your_main.py` in your project directory.  You may have to generate a specification file and edit it for things to work correctly - ***[See the documentation!](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/doc/Manual.html#using-pyinstaller)***

Comment: Did you mean I should change the building directory (pip -b)? The default seems to be under "/private/tmp". Where should I change it to? The "pyinstaller" documents seem not talk about this.

Comment: Also, in the "setup.py" script in the temprory build directory, the very first line is "raise SystemExit("\nsetup.py is not yet supposed to work. "
                 "Please Use PyInstaller without installation.\n")", which seems that this code should never be executated.

Comment: No it is not - it says that it is not - see amended answer above.

Comment: Thanks! I manually downloaded the package and invoked pyinstaller.py explicitly with python, and it seems working fine. At least on my machine, "pip install pyinstaller" will attempt to run setup.py, which may not be supported yet (I could be wrong).

Comment: You are correct - they are working on it but it has a lower priority than other issues at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error before and installing the development version helped when all else did not.