# Unable to install pyinstaller

Tags: macos, installation, pyinstaller

setup.py within the folder raises:

```
setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation.
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159443/pyinstaller-setup-failed-with-setup-py-is-not-yet-supposed-to-work-please-use). I couldn't follow the solution mentioned there. "pip install pyinstaller" raises the same error. I unzipped the 2.0 version but am now stuck on how to proceed. (for clarification - I want to install pyinstaller-2.0 on my machine so that I can use it to bundle Python modules and send it to others). I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767010/how-to-install-pyinstaller) and [this](http://excid3.com/blog/pyinstaller-a-simple-tutorial/#.UhzhG7xbERw) but still no luck. OS = Mountain Lion and Python = 2.7. Pls. help.

Answer (score 0):

I found that installing the development version solved it when I had the problem.