# setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation

Tags: python, pygame, exe, pyinstaller

I am a mac user trying to make my pygame game available for windows as an exe so bear with me. I am trying to use pyinstaller but when I run setup.py it gives me the error:

```
setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation.
```

I have tried installing it with pip as well but get the exact same thing. I am aware of this post:
[pyinstaller setup failed with "setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159443/pyinstaller-setup-failed-with-setup-py-is-not-yet-supposed-to-work-please-use) or though (being pretty noobie) I cant get a solution from the answer. Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/). Download whichever version you want. Unzip the archive. In a console/terminal with admin access go to the directory that contains your unzipped contents. Then do:

`python setup.py install`. That should install pyinstaller for you. Test it out to make sure `pyinstaller` has been added to your PATH so that you can run it from any directory.

After you have installed Pyinstaller using `setup.py`, go to the directory with your game in it and do `pyinstaller game.py`.

For more information, check out [the official documentation](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/develop/doc/Manual.html#installing-from-the-archive) which explains how to use `setup.py` to install from an archive.

Comment: thats exactly what I did but at the end I got the setup.py is not supposed to work message

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I installed the development version after finding this ticket:
http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/756

and now all works fine.